# Unable to install magento on wamp server

Tags: php, mysql, magento, installation

I am unable to install **mangento** on wamp server.

I am using **magento-1.9.1.0** with **PHP Version 5.4.16**

Please have a look following screen, I am getting this error while installing magento in the url http://localhost/magento/index.php/install/wizard/configPost/

[image]

I have done following php.ini settings:

a) max_execution_time = 18000

b) max_input_time = 18000

c) memory_limit = 628M

d) mysql.connect_timeout = -1

I updated above settings but getting an "The connection timed out" issue.

Please suggest. How can we resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you install in 127.0.0.1/magento/index.php ? and when you run that direction the following error appear?

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing problem with magento installation then go to https://bitnami.com/stack/magento and download windows Download Magento Installer. after downloading magento install and specify respective ports and launch you magento application..... 
[image]